# How to fetch variables from yaml and map them in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile with a declarative pipeline. I'm trying to retrieve ECR image names from a config.yml, put them in a map and print them with a loop in Jenkins. Here's what I did so far:

**config.yml:**

```
images:
  - "123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image-1:latest"
  - "123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image-2:latest"
  - "456.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image-9:latest"
```

**jenkinsfile:**

```
def account_info = readYaml file: "config.yml"
def image_info = "${account_info.images}"

def map = [
        ("image") : "${image_info}"
]

pipeline {  
  stages {
    stage('tests') {     
      steps {
        loopImages(map)
      }     
    }
  }
}

def loopImages(map){
  map.each { entry ->
    stage('test-' + entry.key) {
      catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
        script {
          sh """
          echo "${image_info}"
        """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Wanted to know if you recommend I do this in a different way? I'm new to Jenkins and don't really know how to fetch the variables from yaml and put them in a map.

Having it this way is giving me the following error:

```
Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
```

My objective is to have a map like this:

```
def map = [
    ("image") : "123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image-1:latest"
    ("image") : "123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image-2:latest"
    ("image") : "456.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image-9:latest"    
]
```

Comment: This would probably be best done with a Groovy method invoked from the pipeline. Give that a try instead, and once you do, we can assist you if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake here is that you are trying to use a step (`readYaml`) outside of the `pipeline` block. This doesn't work because steps require context from the pipeline, such as the current node.

Really you should see `pipeline` as your main function and don't do much outside of it except simple variable initialization.

For things I have to initialize via steps, I usually create an "Initialize" stage. This keeps things separated and follows single-level of abstraction principle.

```groovy
def account_info = null
def image_info = null
def map = null

pipeline {  
  stages {
    stage('initialize') {
      steps {
        initialize()
      }
    }
    stage('tests') {     
      steps {
        loopImages(map)
      }     
    }
  }
}

void initialize() {
  account_info = readYaml file: "config.yml"
  //... and so on
}
```